# angularjs datepicker should highlight todays date when opened

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am using angularjs datepicker but the issue s if I select a date and perform my operation then next time I open the datepicker for some other record then the record selected for previous record is highlighted. I want the datepicker to reset in controller so that next time i open the datepicker it always highlight todays date. Please suggest a solution if any.

My datepicker syntax:

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" selector="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <label for="casedate" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color: grey;"></label>
                        </span>
                        <input class="form-control admin-reg-font-Roboto" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Select Date" id="addDate" ng-model="$scope.addDateSelected" />
                    </div>
                </datepicker>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: i used init-date but that did not work. Rest i have no idea how can I do for this. there is nothing mentioned in the configuration options as well. Link here.https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Once your operation is completed then set ui datepicker's ng-model value to current date, for example if you are using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" />
```

then once operation is completed, then

```
$scope.dt = new Date();
```

I think that's what you wanted. Or for better answer please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for your solution abhinav but sorry to say it dint work for me.